# Are there any annotations, or other ways to say something is used reflectively?

Tags: java

So occasionally using reflection is useful, and sometimes we access things via both reflection and directly. Is there a good annotation that will suggest a used field/method is also being used reflectively? in case the direct way disappears, then it will not appear to be unused. I realized there's the `@SuppressWarnings('unused')` but that doesn't seem right if it currently is being used directly.

Comment: The unused warning only shows when you are not using private members. Why are you calling a private member using reflection?

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes it also causes IDE's to ignore things that they have determined are unused (or at least the IDE I'm using). It's also worth noting that there are lots of things that use private members reflectively (like JPA)

Comment: If I remember my JPA correctly, it does not access private fields directly; you usually have to wrap them in public getters and setters. Not sure how you ended up with these requirements, but using reflection to access private fields sounds bad. What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Write a unit test that reflectively calls the method of interest.  Then include the unit test with your project.

That way, you will have test-time enforcement that this method is present.  This assumes of course that your tests are run regularly.

Your concern is valid.  If a public method is not referenced in the project, you run the risk that someone else could inadvertently remove it.

This is also a good TDD practice as the unit test expresses the requirements of your software.

Comment: the problem with tests, is it assumes they are a source of truth. Sadly we have software methods that are occasionally unused. Sometimes we try to find them, including the ones only used by tests.

Comment: I'm not sure that I made my point.  It is a good practice to make your tests a source of truth.  A good software organization should use TDD and have unit tests that are run frequently.  If tests are run with the build, and a test failure is configured to break the build, then this functional failure simply cannot make its way into production code.  ==> So you write a test that reflectively calls this method.  If someone removes the method then the next build will break because your test will fail.

Comment: Tests are a bad source of truth, ime. Because they are code they can be buggy. A failing test means some code is wrong. Ime, it is just as often the test; Because test code is written sloppier. In a perfect world you might be right, sadly I live in a world of imperfection.

Comment: FWIW, I too live in a world with many poorly written tests.  And I faced a very similar problem.  Data classes were frequently being modified in a way that changed their XML marshaling behavior (via reflection).  I wrote unit tests to express and validate the expected marshaling behavior - and these tests became the source of truth.  Since doing so 2 years ago, I have not encountered a single instance of this once frequent problem.  So if your organization writes sloppy, buggy tests, do something about it. There's nothing stopping you from writing good tests. It can't hurt to try.

Comment: Also of course we have the problem that then you have code around when in appearance only tests needs it (my IDE can look for that too), so it's somewhat hard to tell by just tests whether the code serves a purpose.

Comment: If you don't want to use this solution, feel free to list all the reasons you think it might not work, rather than just giving it a try.  This approach has worked very well for me and my organization. It sounds like you are not a big fan of unit testing and you are welcome to that opinion.